# Make ASP.NET MVC treat a route parameter named ``id'' like any other parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have an MVC page for creating an entity. Upon completion, I want to redirect to the parent entity. I do it like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = vm.Parent });
```

When I use any other parameter name, it is interpreted as an URL param:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { foo = vm.Parent });
```

renders as `/Entities/Edit?foo=234`

But ASP MVC picks up a route param named `id` as a special case and the URL looks like: `/Entities/Edit/234`. This does not work for me because the routing is not set up to work with this. I am looking to get an URL like `/Entities/Edit?id=234`.

How do I force it to work this way? Route setup:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: In your route config, look for a mapped route that looks like this `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` and add the details to your question.

Comment: Are you using the default routes?

Comment: @spender  added route setup

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you're only using the default route config route, which only specified `id` as a defined `UrlParameter`. If you want a custom parameter, then you'll need to define it as such:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ControllerName",
    url: "controllername/edit/{foo}"
);
```

Or if you wish to use `foo` instead of `id` globally, just alter your existing route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{foo}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", foo = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Or if you don't want good looking URLs with an unnecessary query string parameter, alter your default:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```